# Detecting Active Directory group access?

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to detect granular access to a particular AD group, rather than simply domain access? That is, if I am a member of 2 AD groups - GR_Read_HR, and GR_Write_Finance, is it possible to capture the date I used each of these groups?

Comment: I do not believe so. Permissions are not logged (and not required to be logged). They way they work in Windows, I'm not even sure it could be possible.